# MIN of XML descendats of date type

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery-sql

How can I query min date of all descendants in XML field. Something like this:

```
DECLARE @xml XML ='
<Plan>
    <EffectiveDate>2006-01-01</EffectiveDate>
    <EffectiveDate>2016-09-14</EffectiveDate>
    <EffectiveDate>2016-09-14</EffectiveDate>
    <EffectiveDate>2016-09-14</EffectiveDate>
</Plan>'

SELECT @xml.value('min(descendant::EffectiveDate)','varchar(max)') minDate
    ,@xml.value('count(descendant::EffectiveDate)','varchar(max)') countDate
```

unfortunately above returns NULL for MIN

Comment: I believe this is because SQL-Server does not understand what is the order that you are sorting here, hence it cannot give you the max and min. If you replace the content of the tags to be number (1, 4, 2, 3) instead of (2006-01-01, ....), you will see that it will return a minimum number.

Comment: thanks all. Each answer worked like a charm :). I've chosen Mikael's as I need to query a table with XML column and his way I don't have to do the CROSS APPLY

Comment: I am not sure though which way is the best way from performance perspective as I am testing with real small sample data set. I guess time will tell :). Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default datatype for untyped xml node values is `xdt:untypedAtomic`. The m[in Function (XQuery)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190951.aspx) will try to convert `xdt:untypedAtomic` values to `xs:double` and then return the min value. Your values can not be converted to `xs:double` so `min()` will return the min value of four `null` values.

Since `min()` works just fine on `xs:date` you can first convert your values to `xs:date` and then do the `min()` over the date values.

```sql
declare @xml xml = '
<Plan>
    <EffectiveDate>2006-01-01</EffectiveDate>
    <EffectiveDate>2016-09-14</EffectiveDate>
    <EffectiveDate>2016-09-14</EffectiveDate>
    <EffectiveDate>2016-09-14</EffectiveDate>
</Plan>';

select @xml.value('min(for $n in descendant::EffectiveDate/text() 
                       return $n cast as xs:date?)', 'date'),
       @xml.value('count(descendant::EffectiveDate)', 'int');
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way:

```
DECLARE @xml XML ='
<Plan>
    <EffectiveDate>2006-01-01</EffectiveDate>
    <EffectiveDate>2016-09-14</EffectiveDate>
    <EffectiveDate>2016-09-14</EffectiveDate>
    <EffectiveDate>2016-09-14</EffectiveDate>
</Plan>'

SELECT  MIN(t.v.value('.','date')) minDate,
        COUNT(t.v.value('.','date')) countDate
FROM @xml.nodes('//Plan/EffectiveDate') as t(v)
```

Output:

```
minDate     countDate
2006-01-01  4
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this. I do not think this is the best solution (and I look forward to see a better one here). But it will give you what you want.
**Edited** (The second one which I like better)

```
DECLARE @x XML ='
<Plan>
    <EffectiveDate>2006-01-01</EffectiveDate>
    <EffectiveDate>2016-09-14</EffectiveDate>
    <EffectiveDate>2016-09-14</EffectiveDate>
    <EffectiveDate>2016-09-14</EffectiveDate>
</Plan>';

SELECT
    Min(a.EffDate) AS MinDate
    , Count(a.EffDate) AS CountDate
FROM
(
    SELECT
        EffDate.value('.','DATE') AS EffDate
    FROM
        @x.nodes('/Plan/EffectiveDate') AS Plans(EffDate)
)a;
```

This is the first one.

```
DECLARE @x XML ='
<Plan>
    <EffectiveDate>2006-01-01</EffectiveDate>
    <EffectiveDate>2016-09-14</EffectiveDate>
    <EffectiveDate>2016-09-14</EffectiveDate>
    <EffectiveDate>2016-09-14</EffectiveDate>
</Plan>';

DECLARE @DocHandle INT;
EXEC sp_XML_PrepareDocument @DocHandle OUTPUT, @x;

SELECT Min(a.EffDate) AS MinDate
, Count(a.EffDate) AS CountDate
FROM
(
SELECT *
FROM OPENXML(@DocHandle,'/Plan/EffectiveDate')
WITH (EffDate NVARCHAR(50) '.')
) a

EXEC sp_XML_RemoveDocument @DocHandle;
```